# How to convert hex str into int array

Tags: python, arrays, hex

I have strings of hex, for exemple '01ff6fee32785e366f710df10cc542B4' and I am trying to convert them (efficiently) into an int array 2 characters by 2 characters like [1,255,...].

I tried

```
c = '8db6796fee32785e366f710df10cc542B4' 
c2=[int(x,16) for x in c]
```

but it only takes the characters one by one.
Can i do it without using a for loop (I might be wrong but if think it would be slower) ?

Comment: It's the whole hex number ?

Comment: yes it's 32 characters long

Comment: Your first example '01ff6fee32785e366f710df10cc' is 27 characters!

Comment: Would [binascii.unhexlify()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify) work for you?  It'll convert the 2-character sequences into binary bytes.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed a part of it while copy pasting. Sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could `range(..)` over substrings of length 2:

```
c = '8db6796fee32785e366f710df10cc' 
c2=[int(c[i:i+2],16) for i in range(0,len(c),2)]
```

So `i` iterates of the string with steps of 2 and you take a substring of length 2 from `i` to `i+2` (exclusive) with `c[i:i+2]`. These you convert by taking `int(..,16)`.

For your sample input it generates:

```
>>> c='8db6796fee32785e366f710df10cc'
>>> [int(c[i:i+2],16) for i in range(0,len(c),2)]
[141, 182, 121, 111, 238, 50, 120, 94, 54, 111, 113, 13, 241, 12, 12]
```

The last element is `12` because the length of your string is odd, so it takes `c` as the last element to parse.

Answer (score 3):

For an alternate approach

```
hex_string = '8db6796fee32785e366f710df10cc542B4'
a = bytearray.fromhex(hex_string)
b = list(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> c = '8db6796fee32785e366f710df10c'
>>> [int(x) for x in bytearray.fromhex(c)]
[141, 182, 121, 111, 238, 50, 120, 94, 54, 111, 113, 13, 241, 12]
>>> list(map(int, bytearray.fromhex(c)))
[141, 182, 121, 111, 238, 50, 120, 94, 54, 111, 113, 13, 241, 12]
```

Two relatively simple solutions, but these will error out if the string has an odd number of characters which might or might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found that converting to bytearray first then to numpy array is 15x faster than using int(..) parsing:

```
%%time 
for p in df.phash:
    np.frombuffer(bytearray.fromhex(p), np.uint8)
```