# How to convert an unformatted string with hex values to a numpy int array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am writing a program which gets an unformatted string as an input and should output a numpy int array.
The string contains id, timestamp etc. and a hexadecimal data array. Say the input string is `data_string = '01190810000235a5000235b4000234c5000211a5'`, then `01`is the id, `190810` is the timestamp and `000235a5000235b4000234c5000211a5` is the data array with the values `000235a5, 000235b4, 000234c5, 000211a5`. (The real input string is several MB in size.)

I am having problems converting the data array to a numpy integer array. I have come up with:

```py
import numpy as np
data_dict['data array'] = np.core.defchararray.asarray(data_string[8:], 8)
```

but this way I am only getting a string array. I tried fiddling with `np.fromstring(data_string[8:], np.int32)`, but this changed the given values of the input string. Is there any way to get a int array from a string? Using a for loop (or similar implementiations) is not an option because this code is performance critical.

**EDIT:**
To clarify my problem...

Input string is

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> s = "000235a5000235b4000234c5000211a5"
```

Converting it with `np.core.defchararray.asarray()` results in a `chararray`. But I want a integer type array.

```py
>>> s1 = np.core.defchararray.asarray(s, 8)
>>> s1
chararray(['000235a5', '000235a5', '000235a5', '000235a5'], dtype='<U8')
```

Converting `s` with `np.fromstring()` results in an integer array, but it seems that it does not like hexadecimal numbers.

```py
>>> s2 = np.fromstring(s, dtype=np.int32)
>>> s2
array([842018864, 895563059, 842018864, 878851379, 842018864, 895693875,
       842018864, 895562033])
```

`array([000235a5, 000235a5, 000235a5, 000235a5])` is the result I actually want to get.

Comment: This should be int32, not int8

Comment: Are you aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41848722/how-to-convert-hex-str-into-int-array)? Did you exclude it because of the for loop? How does the data for your first hex numbers look like, as opposed to using `np.fromstring(...)`?

Comment: I searched explicitly for numpy. It looks like the `np.fromstring()` method is converting the hex string to a decimal value before slicing it into an array. I want to preserve the hex values.

Comment: Then, I don't see a solution that avoids loops completely... Somehow, you have to slice the data in pieces of 8 chars then before converting. And this will always include some kind of loop..?

Comment: Isn't there a numpy function which slices the string and _then_ casts it to int?

Comment: @wallisers You can take a look at Numba to do the conversion beforehand.