# decoding bytes coming from tcp client

Tags: python-3.x, tcp

I am getting bytes from a tcp client as:

```
b'\xaa\x01\x00v\x07\x80]\xaf\xf4\x99\x00\x06\x1a\x80\x00\x00Cg\xb0H\xbf<\xe4XBHt\xbf\xbe\xff\xdc\x00AO{\xb3B\x9b/\x91A \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00<\xe7\xd5g\x00\x00\x00\x00<\xa9\x93\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00<\x11\xd1N\x00\x00\x00\x00;\xe2\x19e\x00\x00\x00\x00;>\r\xed\x00\x00\x00\x00:\xf9\tl\x00\x00\x00\x00;\x93t\xbc=\x190\xbe\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00N\xaf'
b'\xaa\x01\x00v\x07\x80]\xaf\xf4\x99\x00\x07\xa1 \x00\x00Cg\x9f \xbf*\xa3\xa0BHuy?5\xa4\x00AO{\xb3B\x9b/\x91A \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00<\xe7\xd5g\x00\x00\x00\x00<\xa9\x93\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00<\x11\xd1N\x00\x00\x00\x00;\xe2\x19e\x00\x00\x00\x00;>\r\xed\x00\x00\x00\x00:\xf9\tl\x00\x00\x00\x00;\x93t\xbc=\x190\xbe\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1c\r'
```

when I am decoding this using:

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1460)
            if not data:
                break
            print(data)
        print(data.decode())
```

it shows the error as:

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: invalid start byte**

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What is the source of these bytes? how were they encoded? You're using `decode` without specifying an encoding so the default is used - UTF-8 (and that is wrong, as you can see from the error)

Comment: You can see in the documentation that the [`decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) function will use UTF-8 as default. Please refer to the following link to see all the supported encodings: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Comment: It is not clear actually what encoding technique they have used. 
It seems I need to perform data parsing on bytes stream received. I have no idea how to do that in Python.

Comment: You can't decode bytes until you knew the encoding used, python will always throw errors when your try to decode bytes using arbitrary decodes, that's simple because not all bytes have meaning to a decoder such as in your case that `utf-8` can't decode the byte `0xaa`

Comment: There was a protocol packet format for that data. And 0xaa was a synchronization byte. 
Thank you for the information though!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the escape sequence, it looks like hex data. 
You can convert remove the escape sequence like show below

```
import binascii
c = binascii.hexlify(data)
```

How to interpret the data then is up to you.

For example you can convert the hex string to say int array.

```
[int(c[i:i+2],16) for i in range(0,len(c),2)]
```

refer [How to convert hex str into int array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41848722/how-to-convert-hex-str-into-int-array)